# Bluetooth scanning and Android location permissions policy

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-location-services

I have an Android app that scans for Bluetooth beacons, I run it as a foreground service and show a notification when scanning. Now, my question is if I start scanning for beacons with a background service, does this mean I have to comply with the location permissions policy?

I also don't want my current app to be banned for not complying (even though everything is in the foreground).

Comment: Foreground service is not a background service. If you remove the foreground service and just use a regular service then yes

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. Also, in regards to location permissions. I do use the FusedLocationProviderClient but removeLocationUpdates after I get the user latitude and longitude in my Splash Activity. In this case, it would be safe for me to not comply with the location permissions policy right? As I do not do anything in the background.